# Setting browser settings in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

Because of some bugs when using Watir in Chrome 103, I've downloaded Chrome Beta 104 and set it as the default browser. Watir still keeps using 103 though.

I've also tried setting the browser version in the parameters but didn't help.

```
prefs = {
  intl: {accept_languages: 'en-GB'},
  browserVersion: '104.0.5112.48' # also tried 'browser_version' and didn't work either
}
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {prefs: prefs}
```

How do I make it use Chrome 104?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Chrome does not properly deal with browserVersion:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3849

You need to pass in:
`binary: '/path/to/beta'`

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities#h.p_ID_106

Comment: Like this? `binary: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome Beta/Application/chrome.exe'` This didn't work either.

Comment: what is the code you are using and the error you are getting?

Comment: Tried this:
`prefs = {
  intl: {accept_languages: 'en-GB'},
  binary: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome Beta/Application/chrome.exe' # 104.0.5112.48
}

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {prefs: prefs}`
Not getting any error, just opens Chrome 103 instead of the beta 104.

Comment: `binary` is not a pref, it goes on the same level as `prefs`